# setInterval for longer hours

Tags: javascript

Is setInterval method reliable for longer hours?
I have a requirement to trigger functions for once everyday and/or once everyweek.
So am using `setInterval(myFunc, 86400000)` //For one day. similarly calculated number of milliseconds for one week
Is this a good approach. or is there anyother technique i can use.

Comment: Is it really feasible that the web page will be open that long?

Comment: The timer would start all over if you closed the page, refreshed, or navigated elsewhere. This doesn't sound like what anyone really wants to do.

Comment: Most likely you'll want to do whatever it is you're doing at the back-end rather than in JS.

Comment: use cron jobs for what you are upto

Comment: Bad idea, but good question about the reliability

Comment: no its not directly in a webpage, its an extension and runs in the background of a browser. So even if the browser is closed the extension runs. Sorry to not mentioning that before.

Comment: @SuneTrudslev How about server side js ?

Comment: @barts Even if it's possible, is it really used in the wild?

Comment: @SuneTrudslev probably not, but the question is about reliability

Answer (score 1):

I think a good option would be,

when the web page opens  first store the date to local storage,
when its open normally check the date in local storage every minute
and then validate it and take action.

setIterval sounds like a very bad way of doing it here...

On start up get the data,

save the date using `localStorage.setItem("date", datevariblename);`

on load or everytime you in the set interval use
`localStorage.getItem("date")` to get the date value

Then do what every comparsion is required between current date and save date

Comment: Seems like fits my requirement. storing the initial timestamp and then validating based on that timestamp might work for me. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: It will use less resources and be more reliable, do you need a working example?

Comment: Updated is that enough or more required? Please upvote/mark correct if helpful !

Comment: yup! that's enough i guess :) Thanks for the quick help. Will buzz you more if required.

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` is pretty darn precise for longer periods. I had the requirement myself some time ago, so I did some testing across browsers. Even if you have a timeout that lasts 24 hours for instance, the callback gets fired precisely (variance is in the area of miliseconds).

`setTimeout` (or more exactly, the implementation) does not use a "countdown". It will ask the  operating system to give it a `SIG`nal when the time period is over.

Comment: It's browser/platform dependent though :)

Comment: @SuneTrudslev: for sure it is. But as I described, ES implementations work together with OS signals and timers, so this is very reliable.

Comment: thanks! i will give a try with this as well. my extension if for chrome and on all operating systems.